# VHDL Multidimension Array creation from subtype to type

Tags: multidimensional-array, vhdl, fpga

Edit.....

If I create type A
where...

```
type A is array (0 to arr_d1_len - 1) of std_logic_vector(wordlength-1 downto 0);
```

And I set a new type which is an array of type A to...

```
type B is array (0 to arr_d2_length - 1) of A;
```

Once I have a signal...

```
signal my_sig : B;
```

How can I work out the dimension order? as I have 3 dimensions in total there are 6 possible variations (admittedly some wouldn't make that much sense) however,  e.g.

```
my_sig(wordlength-1 downto 0) (0 to arr_d2_length - 1) (0 to arr_d1_length - 1);
```

Also how would this problem work for higher dimension problems? e.g. 4 or 5 arrays stacked in this style...

Comment: Several issues here: A cannot be a subtype, it is a type. A subtype is a constrained version of an existing type, not a new type. 

Second, you have declared all of the dimensions in the types, so you only have 1 possible direction (and size) for any object of type B.

Finally, you cannot slice a slice. You can only slice a single element.

Comment: B has one index. It's a single-dimensional array type not a multidimensional array type. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types, 8.4 Slice names, 8.5 slice names.

Comment: I have edited the question according to the subtype error... how can i access the lower dimensions of the array? and in what order do i do it?